# How would I return a 1 mile radius in longitude/latitude from a provided longitude and latitude point with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Every page I have has meta data that looks like the following:

```
<meta property="og:latitude" content="47.619113">
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-122.235369">
```

What I want to return is a polygon radius that is a 1 mile radius of these given coordinates. How would I do this with jQuery?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense as latitude and longitude are fixed points, not a radius. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a circular polygon long/lat radius around this point! This is what I meant. I'm sorry.

Comment: Take a look at [Turf.js Circle](https://turfjs.org/docs/#circle)

Comment: It seems this question implies some sort of map server is being used, either served internally or, more likely, an API you're interfacing with. If there's some other context you could provide, like what you're trying to accomplish, specifically, once you have computed this radius, it might help you get a clearer answer. I'm guessing you want something like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator

Comment: All I want is to return a 1 mile polygon coordinate around that give long/lat point. I am always given a lat/long point on the page, I just need to create the math to figure polygon coordinates for 1 mile around that point somehow. It would look like this for example: 47.637572513170646%2C-122.23440644180297%3B47.634275856241935%2C-122.24225994979858%3B47.628867731741934%2C-122.2423886958313

Comment: Choices are use a library as I linked above or dig into the trigonometry/distance calcs yourself stepping through 0-360 degrees in a loop. The math won't be very complicated and is easy to research

Comment: you're looking for a circle, and you already know it's radius and it's center. I don't understand what else do you need. It's diameter would be 2πR and it's area would be πR². As the radius is 1, diameter will be π times 2 and it's area will be π square miles. You don't need infinite coordinates to draw it, if that's what you're trying to do. There are many tools available for that.